# Software to keep track of the progress/development of around 40 people

Tags: windows

I have a hard time finding the proper terms to use but I will outline my situation and based on that I will try to explain what sort of software I'm looking for.

I work in a supervised living group where adolescents live and get help with finding a job, getting welfare, the right psychological help, etc...
My task is partially to be a janitor, partially to assist the residents and make sure they comply to the house rules. I write a report for the counsellors after every shift. I'm one of a team of 6 assistants.

Now we keep track of the progress of the inhabitants in two ways:

- Folders with all their information (contact details, annotations, psychological history). These are private and only accessible by their counsellors (not me).
- Bi-daily report which contain all information about the residents and the house. These are accessible by all workers (including me). These reports are printed and stored in a folder.

I'm looking for a way to digitize the latter. The software has to do the following:

- Create objects per resident. These objects should be visualised as a page.
- Per object at least a photo and several text fields need to be assigned.
- An integrated simple text editor should be available to write the daily reports.
- The objects should be linkable in the reports.
- Full-text search of the reports.
- A plus: tracking of who wrote what (a bit like track changes in Word).

So I'm looking for some sort of project-management tool for people.

**A usage scenario:**
Jack (a resident) didn't comply to the rules and as a result of that he can not receive visitors for a month. Now this is notified to everyone through the bi-daily reports. If 3 weeks later I catch Jack with some visitors I have to manually browse all the reports of the previous 3 weeks to see when Jack's visitor restriction has been issued.

With the digital system I envision that I just go to Jacks page, read the annotation where it said that he had a visitor restriction, note the date and determine if he can have visitors or not.

Because of privacy concerns the system should be working off-line.

Comment: Should it work on several computers of a local network? Or is it OK if it runs only on a single computer?

Comment: It should work a small (2 pc's) network.